# Find the number of subsets of $\{1, 2, . . . , 15\}$ s.t. no two elements of $S$ are relatively prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the sum of digits of the number of subsets $S$ of $\{1, 2, . . . , 15\}$ such that $S$ has at least two elements and no two elements of $S$ are relatively prime.

So here is how I tried it.

Taking common factor $2$ we will get the set $\{2,4,6,...,14\}$, number of its subsets is $2^7-7-1=120$.

Taking common factor $3$. The set is $\{3,6,9,12,15\}$
which gives $2^5-5-1-1$ (because the set $\{6,12\}$ is already covered in above mentioned) $=26$ subsets.

Taking $5$: $\{5,10,15\}$. It gives $2^3-3-1=4$ subsets.

Similarly by $7$ we will get $1$ subset.

Adding them up: $120+26+4+1=151$.

Hence the answer should be $1+5+1=7$. But it states $9$.

Please help me spot my error. TY in advance:D

Comment: The subset $\{6,10,15\}$ is never counted. A subset doesn’t have to have a common divisor for all of its numbers.

Comment: If your method is right and your result is bad it could be maybe because you have discarded the element $\{\phi\}$ which IS AN ELEMENT of the set of subsets of your initial set.

Comment: @Piquito I don't think that is to be counted since each subset requires at least two elements.

Comment: It is **true**  that there are no two elements of $\emptyset$  that are relatively prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let us add the subsets that you are missing. There are only three of them: $$\{6,10,15\},$$ $$\{10,12,15\},$$ $$\{6,10,12,15\}.$$ You missed them because each of them doesn’t have a (non-trivial) common divisor for all its elements.

You found all the other subsets though, but made a mistake while counting: $2^5-5-1-1=25$, not $26$. So there are $150$ of them.

What numbers can not be in a subset, if every two its elements have a common divisor, but there is no common divisor for all of them?

- Clearly, $1$ can’t be there, it’s coprime with anything.
- Primes can’t be there, they have only one (non-trivial) divisor, so any other number in a subset has to have it, too.
- Powers of primes can’t be either, for the same reason.
- Number $14=2\cdot 7$ can’t be there, too. It can have a common divisor only with $7$ (but there is no $7$, it’s prime and has already been ruled out) and with even numbers. All the numbers in a subset are even then, we have already counted that.

What is left? Numbers $$6=2\cdot3,$$ $$10=2\cdot5,$$ $$12=2^2\cdot3,$$ $$15=3\cdot5.$$

Every number here has a $2$ as a common factor, except $15$. So $15$ must be in a subset for sure. Same with factor $3$: number $10$ has to be in a subset. We must add at least one more number, so there are $3$ ways to build a subset we look for: adding $6$, adding $12$, or adding both of them.

The final answer is $150+3=153$ then. The sum of digits is indeed $9$.

Comment: Yo thanks man appreciate it:)